# Почему не работает margin: 0 auto?

Tags: html, css, margin

Все, что находится на странице, завернуто в `<div class="content_block"></div>`, и это все должно располагаться по центру. Для этого – `margin: 0 auto;`.

Но к сожалению, центрирование не работает.

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding-top: 45px;
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.content_block {
    width: 1660px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-right: 40px;
    padding-left: 40px;
}

.header_menu ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: black;
}

.header_menu ul li a.posttypes {
    color: #b59f5b;
}

.header_menu ul li a.posttypes:after {
    content:"";
    border-width: 4px;
    border-color: #b59f5b transparent transparent transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    position: relative;
    top: 11px;
    left: 3px;
}

.header_menu > ul .menu_el:after {
    content:"";
    border-width: 4px;
    border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    position: relative;
    top: 11px;
    left: 3px;
}

.header_menu > ul li {
    list-style: none;
    margin-right: 35px;
}

.header_menu > ul li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0px;
}

.header_menu > ul li, .logo_icons {
    display: inline-block;
}

.header_menu > ul li ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}

.header_menu ul li:hover > ul{
    display: block;
}


.header_menu ul li ul li {
    display: block;
    padding-top: 20px;
}


.logo_icons {
    display: flex;
}

.logo_icons svg {
    margin-right: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.logo_icons svg:last-child {
    margin-right: 0px;
}

.icon {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
}

.google {
    width: 23px;
    height: 15px;
}

.facebook {
    width: 8px;
    height: 15px;
}

.heading {
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 90px;
    width: 1603px;
    text-align: center;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 70px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 3.51px;
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
    position: relative;
}

h1:after {
    content: "";
    width: 66px;
    height: 3px;
    background: #b59f5b;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-33px);
}

.groups_line {
  width: 1565px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-right: 40px;
    padding-left: 40px;
  display: flex;
}

.line {
    width: 519px;
    height: 360px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    position: relative;
}

.line:last-child {
    margin-right: 0px;
}

.first_group {
    background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/L8tyDfNC/13-2x.png);
}

.second_group {
    background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/QNRGnQJh/kaboompics-com-Woman-preparing-a-lunch-on-the-kitchen-table.png);
}

.third_group {
    background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/76fdKhC5/photo-1453822858805-7c095c06011e.png);
}

.border {
    position: absolute; 
    width: 466px;
    height: 134px;
    border: 3px solid #b59f5b;
    top: 170px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="content_block">
        <header>
            <div class="header_menu">
                <ul>
                    <li class="menu_el"><a href="">home</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="">friendship</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">love</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">relationship</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">food</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">sport</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menu_el"><a href="">features</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="">friendship</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">love</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">relationship</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">food</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">sport</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="posttypes"><a class="posttypes" href="">posttypes</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="">friendship</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">love</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">relationship</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">food</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">sport</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menu_el"><a href="">pages</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="">friendship</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">love</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">relationship</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">food</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">sport</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menu_el"><a href="">categories</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="">friendship</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">love</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">relationship</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">food</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">sport</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menu"><a href="">contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <svg display="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                    <symbol id="twitter" viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="15px">
                        <path d="M512,97.248c-19.04,8.352-39.328,13.888-60.48,16.576c21.76-12.992,38.368-33.408,46.176-58.016
                        c-20.288,12.096-42.688,20.64-66.56,25.408C411.872,60.704,384.416,48,354.464,48c-58.112,0-104.896,47.168-104.896,104.992
                        c0,8.32,0.704,16.32,2.432,23.936c-87.264-4.256-164.48-46.08-216.352-109.792c-9.056,15.712-14.368,33.696-14.368,53.056
                        c0,36.352,18.72,68.576,46.624,87.232c-16.864-0.32-33.408-5.216-47.424-12.928c0,0.32,0,0.736,0,1.152
                        c0,51.008,36.384,93.376,84.096,103.136c-8.544,2.336-17.856,3.456-27.52,3.456c-6.72,0-13.504-0.384-19.872-1.792
                        c13.6,41.568,52.192,72.128,98.08,73.12c-35.712,27.936-81.056,44.768-130.144,44.768c-8.608,0-16.864-0.384-25.12-1.44
                        C46.496,446.88,101.6,464,161.024,464c193.152,0,298.752-160,298.752-298.688c0-4.64-0.16-9.12-0.384-13.568
                        C480.224,136.96,497.728,118.496,512,97.248z"/>
                    </symbol>
                    <symbol id="facebook" viewBox="22 0 53.124 96.123" width="9px">
                        <path d="M72.089,0.02L59.624,0C45.62,0,36.57,9.285,36.57,23.656v10.907H24.037c-1.083,0-1.96,0.878-1.96,1.961v15.803
                        c0,1.083,0.878,1.96,1.96,1.96h12.533v39.876c0,1.083,0.877,1.96,1.96,1.96h16.352c1.083,0,1.96-0.878,1.96-1.96V54.287h14.654
                        c1.083,0,1.96-0.877,1.96-1.96l0.006-15.803c0-0.52-0.207-1.018-0.574-1.386c-0.367-0.368-0.867-0.575-1.387-0.575H56.842v-9.246
                        c0-4.444,1.059-6.7,6.848-6.7l8.397-0.003c1.082,0,1.959-0.878,1.959-1.96V1.98C74.046,0.899,73.17,0.022,72.089,0.02z"/>
                    </symbol>
                    <symbol id="in" viewBox="0 0 552.77 552.77" width="15px">
                        <path d="M17.95,528.854h71.861c9.914,0,17.95-8.037,17.95-17.951V196.8c0-9.915-8.036-17.95-17.95-17.95H17.95
                        C8.035,178.85,0,186.885,0,196.8v314.103C0,520.816,8.035,528.854,17.95,528.854z"/>
                        <path d="M17.95,123.629h71.861c9.914,0,17.95-8.036,17.95-17.95V41.866c0-9.914-8.036-17.95-17.95-17.95H17.95
                        C8.035,23.916,0,31.952,0,41.866v63.813C0,115.593,8.035,123.629,17.95,123.629z"/>
                        <path d="M525.732,215.282c-10.098-13.292-24.988-24.223-44.676-32.791c-19.688-8.562-41.42-12.846-65.197-12.846
                        c-48.268,0-89.168,18.421-122.699,55.27c-6.672,7.332-11.523,5.729-11.523-4.186V196.8c0-9.915-8.037-17.95-17.951-17.95h-64.192
                        c-9.915,0-17.95,8.035-17.95,17.95v314.103c0,9.914,8.036,17.951,17.95,17.951h71.861c9.915,0,17.95-8.037,17.95-17.951V401.666
                        c0-45.508,2.748-76.701,8.244-93.574c5.494-16.873,15.66-30.422,30.488-40.649c14.83-10.227,31.574-15.343,50.24-15.343
                        c14.572,0,27.037,3.58,37.393,10.741c10.355,7.16,17.834,17.19,22.436,30.104c4.604,12.912,6.904,41.354,6.904,85.33v132.627
                        c0,9.914,8.035,17.951,17.949,17.951h71.861c9.914,0,17.949-8.037,17.949-17.951V333.02c0-31.445-1.982-55.607-5.941-72.48
                        S535.836,228.581,525.732,215.282z"/>
                </symbol>
                <symbol id="instagram" viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="15px">
                    <g>
                        <path d="M352,0H160C71.648,0,0,71.648,0,160v192c0,88.352,71.648,160,160,160h192c88.352,0,160-71.648,160-160V160
                        C512,71.648,440.352,0,352,0z M464,352c0,61.76-50.24,112-112,112H160c-61.76,0-112-50.24-112-112V160C48,98.24,98.24,48,160,48
                        h192c61.76,0,112,50.24,112,112V352z"/>
                    </g>
                    <g>
                        <path d="M256,128c-70.688,0-128,57.312-128,128s57.312,128,128,128s128-57.312,128-128S326.688,128,256,128z M256,336
                        c-44.096,0-80-35.904-80-80c0-44.128,35.904-80,80-80s80,35.872,80,80C336,300.096,300.096,336,256,336z"/>
                    </g>
                    <g>
                        <circle cx="393.6" cy="118.4" r="17.056"/>
                    </g>
                </symbol>
                <symbol id="google" viewBox="0 4 24 16" width="23px">
                    <path d="m21.823 9h-2.187v2.177h-2.177v2.187h2.177v2.177h2.187v-2.177h2.177v-2.187h-2.177z"/><path d="m7.5 19.5c4.328 0 7.203-3.038 7.203-7.326 0-.491-.051-.87-.122-1.248h-7.08v2.578h4.257c-.174 1.095-1.289 3.233-4.257 3.233-2.557 0-4.645-2.118-4.645-4.737s2.087-4.738 4.645-4.738c1.463 0 2.435.624 2.988 1.156l2.036-1.954c-1.311-1.227-2.999-1.964-5.025-1.964-4.144 0-7.5 3.356-7.5 7.5s3.356 7.5 7.5 7.5z"/>
                </symbol>
            </svg>

            <div class="logo_icons">
                <svg class="twitter icon">
                    <use xlink:href="#twitter"></use>
                </svg>
                <svg class="facebook">
                    <use xlink:href="#facebook"></use>
                </svg>
                <svg class="in icon">
                    <use xlink:href="#in"></use>
                </svg>
                <svg class="instagram icon">
                    <use xlink:href="#instagram"></use>
                </svg>
                <svg class="google">
                    <use xlink:href="#google"></use>
                </svg>
            </div>
        </header>
    <div class="heading">
        <h1>Noémi</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="groups_line">
        <div class="first_group line">
            <div class="first-group-line border">
                <p class="group_line heading">beauty   health  lifestyle</p>
                <p class="group_line text">FROM GRAPEFRUIT TO LEMONS TO ORANGES, CITRUS DOES YOU GOOD!</p>
                <p class="group-line data">June 14, 2015</p>
                <div class="group-line comment_logo">
                    <p class="group-line number">24</p>
                    <i class="fas fa-comment"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="second_group line">
            <div class="second-group-line border">
                <p class="group_line heading">Hello</p>
                <p class="group_line text">hi   </p>
                <p class="group-line data"> </p>
                <div class="group-line comment_logo">
                    <p class="group-line number"></p>
                    <i class="fas fa-comment"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="third_group line">
            <div class="third-group-line border">
                <p class="group_line heading"></p>
                <p class="group_line text"> </p>
                <p class="group-line data"> </p>
                <div class="group-line comment_logo">
                    <p class="group-line number"></p>
                    <i class="fas fa-comment"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/Van245/pen/OJNdKOq?editors=1100)

Как это исправить? Огромное спасибо:)

Comment: Скорее всего нужно исправить width: 1660px; на что-то поменьше. Например 1000px. Если у вас монитор с разрешением 1366px по ширине то .content-block не будет по центру так как его размер больше.

Comment: Запустил ваш пример, проблему не увидел, всё лежит в точности по центру https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOhGJ.png

Comment: @andreymal, как я понял не центровано меню (`header`)

Comment: @andreymal потому что у тебя монитор 1920px, а в стилях стоит размер 1600px вот поэтому ты и не видишь.

Answer (score 1):

```
header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-beetween;
    padding-top: 45px;
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

замените

```
    justify-content: space-beetween;
```

на

```
    justify-content: space-around;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так документ не по центру, посмотри на отступ в левой и правой части.

Comment: @MARSHAL, почему? заголовок (`header`) выровнен по центу, он содержит меню (слева) и контакты (всякие иконки соцсетей) справа - расстояние слева от меню и справа от иконок одинаковое, т.е. вся плашка заголовка выровнена по центру

Comment: Нафига это заменять? Какое вообще отношение это имеет к вопросу?

Answer (score 1):

Что-бы страница стала по центру вам нужно заменить следующие строки кода:

```
.content_block {
width: 90vw;
margin: 0 auto;
padding-right: 40px;
padding-left: 40px;
}

.heading {
margin-top: 60px;
margin-bottom: 90px;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}

.groups_line {
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
padding-right: 40px;
padding-left: 40px;
display: flex;
}
```

В .content_block заменим на

**vw** (viewport width) - процентное соотношение ширины окна. Допустим окно шириной 800px, 10vw это 10% от ширины **ИМЕННО ОКНА**, то есть 80 px; Если окно меняет ширину, допустим было 800px а стало 1000px, то 10vw сначала будет равен 80px, а потом 100px.

Есть еще **vh**, принцип такой-же как у **vw** только предназначен для высоты окна.

Answer (score 0):

Всё работает - вот скриншот со сниппета из вопроса:

[image: скриншот]